# How can I improve this ajax call so that it can be used globally?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

I am building a site for my professor and am trying not to repeat my code, because i will be failed for this.

I have the following .getJson call that I would like to use in multiple locations so that i do not have to repeat code superfluously.

```
function GetJSON()
{
    var a = $.getJSON("/controller_name/action", null, function (z) {})
    .success(function (z) {
              //Success Action
    })
    .error(function (z) {
              //Error Action
    })
    .complete(function (z) {
              //Complete Action
    });
}
```

I could pass in variables the success, error, and complete events, but I thought that this way has the potential to get very messy.  Is there a way to set this up so that I do not have to have the same function GetJSON all over my site.

Comment: I don't see how wrapping the `$.getJSON` function in another function will reduce your code... Just call `$.getJSON` in each instance where it is needed. Your `$.getJSON` wrapper function will only be able to forward arguments to the actual `$.getJSON` function, creating overhead in the process. If you have some function(s) that need to be run for every AJAX call then use Global AJAX Events: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Comment: well, it would reduce it if there's other stuff supplied to the AJAX call or data that has been omitted from this sample code.  If there's multiple calls to this function it also removes the duplication of the URL all over the code.

Comment: @some_bloody_fool If possible I'd like to see the code you end up writing (the actual code you will turn-in to your professor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your professor is up to date with current paradigms, you should be *returning* `a` (the returned value of `$.getJSON`).

It's a *deferred* object, and you can attach handlers to it any time you please, and don't have to attach them within your own `GetJSON()` function.

If you have common actions that you *always* want to happen, put those inside the `GetJSON()` function, and use the externally bound handlers for actions that are unique:

```
function GetJSON()
{
    var a = $.getJSON("/controller_name/action", null, function (z) {
        ...
    });

    // bind functions that you always want to happen here
    a.fail(function(z) {
        console.log("something bad happened");
    });

    return a;
}

var d = GetJSON();

// bind additional functions here
d.done(
     // Success Action
})
.fail(function (z) {
     // Error Action
})
.always(function (z) {
     // Complete Action
});
```

Note that jQuery 1.7 has deprecated `.success`, `.error` and `.complete` in favour of the functions used above, for consistency with other Deferred objects.

Comment: can you please point me in the right direction.  Do you mean replace z with a? i thought that was just a variable?

Comment: @some_bloody_fool It's the `a` of `var a = $.getJSON()`;

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say that's repeating code actually IMHO (unless you make the same request and update the same elements everytime). If the callbacks en request url are different everytime there isn't really a need to write a 'wrapper' for it IMHO.

The way I see it as a 'native' function. E.g. `console.log()` for example. You don't want to write a function which wraps around that do you?

That being said if you really need / want to do it you would just have to pass all params / callbacks to the function.

Comment: Ironically, having a wrapper around console.log() prevents the errors that inevitably occur and break everything in environments where console.log isn't defined...